# Animated loader gif not spinning

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html file with some javascript that takes some time to run, and I want to show an animated loader gif while the user is waiting.
The problem is that the animation does not work.
I tried some solution. Some of them from stack overflow, but nothing really worked.
I'm limited for using IE8 only.

Does someone knows of a solution that works well?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RunAndShow() {
            document.getElementById("circularG").style.display = "block";
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var j = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
                    j = i;
                }
                alert("done");
            }, 1500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circularG" style="width:200px;height:200px;display:none; background-image:url(ajax-loader.gif)">
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="RunAndShow()">Run & Show</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/d83Kw/1/ There you have an example of how you should do it. BTW this is the first entry if you google 'animated background gif css', just saying

Comment: @Pinki no, it still freezes the gif when js is running for a long time (on Chrome at least): http://jsfiddle.net/xje8stqx/ If you don't see it, add a `0` in the loop.

Comment: @Pinki. It is stuck.

Comment: @Itay.B the animation only freezes when a javascript popup is opened. This will block a HTMl page

Comment: @devqon The animation freezes while JS is running too, try it (should stay frozen for about 3-8secs): http://jsfiddle.net/6o7jqh6s/

Comment: @blex well try not to use a loop in javascript like that then? No browser can cope with the things you want him to do with this loop....

Comment: What happens if you load the image directly in your browser (just type the URL of your server + `/ajax-loader.gif`).

Comment: It's likely the browser terminating the animating thread after a period of time. Many modern browsers do this as a performance enhancement. Absolutely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @phari, I thought about web worker but it sounded like too big of a deal for  such a small task.

Comment: I tried it now in Chrome. Same thing. Stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're having a long running for loop inside the `RunAndShow` the JS process becomes busy. So it blocks the UI thread in browser. It's expected behavior.

You can use webworkers to run long running computation. But as you are limited to IE8, it's not available.

One option is to use setInterval/setTimeout and do the heavy computation partially each time so that the UI thread doesn't block.

```
    function RunAndShow() {

        document.getElementById("circularG").style.display = "block";

        window.setTimeout(function () {

            var computed = 0, process = 500, total = 10000000000, j;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                while(computed < process && process < total ) {
                    j = computed;
                    computed++;
                }
                process += 500;
                if(process >= total) {
                 clearInterval(interval);
                 alert("done");
                }
            }, 10); // increase the delay

        }, 1500);

    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/6o7jqh6s/1/)**

Comment: I can't do it partially. In my real code it's one long task.

Comment: This is really working for a task that you can do in small chunks. But my task is one long task.

Comment: In that case, webworker is the only choice. As in question you mentioned just for Loop i felt this could solve that.

Comment: It does solve it. In IE8 do I have webworker at all?

Comment: No. It's not available in IE8.

Comment: Ok. Do you think Q.Js when then practice will work here?

Comment: No. Your problem is not about asynchronous execution. But it's a long running task which is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: That's the point in "Then". Meaning, until then, don't block the UI.

Comment: Nope. Then is to execute a callback function after execution. But here the long running task is blocking browser's ui thread. It has nothing to do with promise

Answer (score -1):

Here is a website with lots of animated gifs for loading: http://preloaders.net/
They all work in IE8

Comment: That's not the problem though, the javascript is.